# How to justify right and left the scientific values in table

Tags: tables

As seen in the picture below, the length of some scientific values are shorter than the others due to use of + and - sign. + sign occupies more space than -. Values are aligned left by default. How to align left and right(justify)?

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Functions}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FCDE} &         \multicolumn{2}{c}{POBL-ADE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FWA-DE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FERDE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CDEOA} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean Error±Std Dev} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean Error±Std Dev} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean Error±Std Dev} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean Error±Std Dev} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean Error±Std Dev} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}[5]{*}{\parbox{1.4cm}{\textit{Unimodal Functions}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$F_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{6.54E+04±4.90E+04} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.60E+04±1.22E+04} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{+} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.76E+05±1.82E+05} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5.41E+02±5.41E+02} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{+} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.64E+04±4.26E+04} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$F_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.00E+00±0.00E+00} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\approx$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.14E+02±7.52E+02} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.00E+00±1.87E-16} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\approx$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.39E-03±2.39E-03} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.00E+00±8.01E-13} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$F_3$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.51E+01±1.26E+02} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.00E+00±4.59E-09} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\approx$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.00E+00±4.74E-16} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{+} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.13E-03±1.13E-03} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.05E-05±6.68E-05} \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
\end{adjustbox}
\label{tab:table3}%
\end{table*}%
```

[image]

Comment: Could you precise a bit more the behavior you want to achieve? Also, please try to provide a complete minimal working example (one starting with `\documentclass{article}` and ending with `\end{document}`, so that it can be compiled directly).

Comment: If you want the justify the standard deviations separately from the data, put them into two columns using l@{}l

Comment: I suggest to use the capabilities of package `siunitx` to deal with values in tables. Is quite handy in the document body as well to write numbers with their respective units.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you *provide a  complete minimal working example (one starting with \documentclass{article} and ending with \end{document}, so that it can be compiled directly).*

Comment: all the other comments are relevant.  for a minimalistic approach, just wrap a *hyphen* in `$-$` to get the real minus sign.  (plus just happens to work but it's really an accident.  that would also best be put between dollar signs.)

Comment: From a scientific view, shouldn't the std deviation be expressed with the same exponent, to make differences comparable? Also, what are those minus, plus and approx signs doing? I don't know what the doc is about, but that is quite confusing. Also, you are using an automatic tool that outputs that *crappy*  table. You would have been long done if you would have invested in some manual work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton ^^^^^^

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use siunitx and its really powerfull `S` table specifier.

You then just have to adjust your numbering slightly and give the correct `table-format`-option. Here it is `1.2(3)e-2` because you have 1 digit before the decimal point, two digits after it, 3 digits for the standard deviation and 2 digits plus a sign in the exponent.

For more on that, please consider the documentation:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf

Here is what I have done with your table (i did not include everything):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \tiny
  \centering
  \caption{Set with booktabs and siunitx}
  \label{tab:table3}%
  \begin{tabular}{c *{5}{S[table-format=1.2(3)e-2]}}
  \toprule
  {Functions} & {FCDE} & {POBL-ADE} &  {FWA-DE} & {FERDE} & {CDEOA} \\
  \midrule
  $F_1$ & 6.54+-4.90e+04 & 1.60+-1.22e+04 & 2.76+-1.82e+05 & 5.41+-5.41e+02 &  4.64+-4.26e+04 \\
  $F_2$ & 0.00+-0.00e+00 & 3.14+-7.52e+02 & 0.00+-1.87e-16 & 2.39+-2.39e-03 & 0.00+-8.01e-13 \\
  $F_3$ & 0.35+-1.26e+02 & 0.00+-4.59e-09 & 0.00+-4.74e-16 & 1.13+-1.13e-03 & 1.05+-6.68e-05 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

Most of the numbers you have in this table are kind of suspicious to me. Mostly because the errors are an order of magnitude greater than the value or because 0±1e-16 smells like numerical problems and should be exactly 0.

Also keep the table more simple. Those signs and redundant informations make it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to find package for scientific notation, where would have + and - same size. However, the most convenient way to align things in LaTeX tables is just to make separated columns for it.
From..

`& \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.00E+00±0.00E+00} &`

do something like...

`& 0.00 & E+00 & ±0.00 & E+00 &`

Than of course you have redefine columns of table at header and change multicolumn number in members of first two rows.

I am also not following, why you have multicolumns everywhere.

Comment: It's one way to change the alignment from r to l.